# Dockerfile with Go can't find path

Tags: docker, go

I have an issue getting my local build to run as well as getting my Dockerfile configured.

My project structure looks like:

```
project
- cmd
  main.go
- internal
  - app
    app.go
Dockerfile
```

So, in `main.go` I say

```
import (
    "project/internal/app"
)
```

Then, when I say `go build` I can run locally perfectly.

However, in my Dockerfile I say

```
FROM golang
ENV GOPATH /go/src/github.com/project
COPY . /go/src/github.com/project
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/project
RUN make linux
```

And I get the issue:

```
cmd/main.go:4:2: cannot find package "Slaxtract/internal/app" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/project/internal/app (from $GOROOT)
    /go/src/github.com/project/src/project/internal/app (from $GOPATH)
```

Why is Docker adding `src` to the GOPATH? And how can I configure it to look in the right spot?

If I change my `main.go` to be a relative path I can hack a fix - but then I can't run locally as I get

```
main.go:4:2: local import "../internal/app" in non-local package
```

Any and all help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Go expects to find folders like `src`, `pkg` and `bin` within `GOPATH`. However, you're pointing it into in fact your project folder.
To fix it you just need to point your `GOPATH` into `/go`.

So your `Dockerfile` should look like

```
FROM golang
ENV GOPATH /go
COPY . /go/src/github.com/project
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/project
RUN make linux
```

You can find more information on `GOPATH` [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GOPATH).
If you're tired of `GOPATH` you can give a try to [gomodules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules)

Comment: Also note that, with this directory structure, your Go package name should start with `"github.com/project/..."`.

Comment: @DavidMaze package name on import you mean